# What is the difference and purpose of auto and escaping closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I am looking for some of the difference/purpose of autoclosure and escaping closure in Swift. I know well that an escaping closure is something we want to execute after the function has been returned but I didn't get the concept of an autoclosure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I didn't get the concept of autoclosure closure.

The *autoclosure* allows a function to wrap an expression in a closure so that it can be executed later or not at all.

A good example of the use of an *autoclosure* is the [*short-circuit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) behavior that happens with `||`.

Consider this example:

```
func willCrash() -> Bool {
    fatalError()
    return true
}

let good = true

if good || willCrash() {
    print("made it")
}
```

Output:

> ```
> made it
> ```

The `||` operator uses short-circuit evaluation: The left-hand side (lhs) is evaluated first, and the right-hand side (rhs) is evaluated only if lhs evaluates to false.

So, how is that implemented?  Well, `||` is simply a function that takes two arguments that each evaluate to a `Bool` and `||` combines them to return a `Bool`.  But in the normal calling scheme of a function in Swift, the arguments are evaluated *before* the function is called.  If `||` was implemented in the obvious way:

```
func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs ? true : rhs
}
```

it would crash because of the execution of `willCrash()` before `||` was called.  So `||` employs *autoclosure* to wrap the second statement in a *closure* so that it can **delay evaluation** until it is inside the `||` function.  If the first statement (which is evaluated before `||` was called) is `true` then the result of the `||` is `true` and the *closure* is not called thus avoiding the crash in this example.

Here is the definition of `||`:

> ```
> static func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
> ```
>
> **Description**    Performs a logical OR operation on two Bool values. The logical OR operator (||) combines two Bool values and returns true
>   if at least one of the values is true. If both values are false, the
>   operator returns false.
>
> This operator uses short-circuit evaluation:
>   The left-hand side (lhs) is evaluated first, and the right-hand side
>   (rhs) is evaluated only if lhs evaluates to false.

Ignoring the *throws/rethrows* which is another topic, the implementation of `||` becomes:

```
func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) -> Bool {
    return lhs ? true : rhs()
}
```

and `rhs()` is only called when `lhs == false`.

Comment: why does second parameter throws? is it requirement for autoclosures?

Comment: It's not a requirement, but it ensures the proper handling of a function that throws if you use it on the right hand side of the `||`.  Since the rhs is delayed, you want to make sure that the `||` operator sees the throw and rethrows it so that it can be returned to the function using the `||` operator.

Comment: I see, I wanted to ask to clarify additional point but I figured out the answer while formulating the question. Rubber duck strikes again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I beleive the key point here is that autoclosure execution is delayed . hence in your case willCrash() on lhs will not be called untill it is inside the function ||. Hence it prevents the crash.

Comment: So, If I am not mistaking, for such a case if `rhs` wouldn't be marked as `@autoclosure` it will definitely crash, right?

Comment: @AhmadF, you are right.  Without `@autoclosure` the `rhs` will be evaluated before `||` is called and it will crash.  The short-circuiting works because the call to `willCrash()` is wrapped in a closure that is never called if `lhs` is `true`.

Comment: @vacawama I would appreciate your  kindness if you would check this code to understand my point: `func willCrash() -> Bool {
    fatalError()
    return true
}

func compare(lhs: Bool, rhs: () -> Bool) {
    if lhs {
        print("lhs is true")
    } else if rhs() {
        print("rhs is true")
    }
}

compare(lhs: true, rhs: willCrash)` at some point, there is no need to access `rhs` so there is no crash... what I mean is: is it necessary to mark it `rhs` as  `@autoclosure` for the `||` operator?

Comment: In your example, you are forcing the caller to pass a function or closure as the second argument.  If Swift didn't use `@autoclosure` for `||` then the user would either have to provide a closure themselves or a function call that returns `Bool` for the `rhs` which would be annoying.  `if a == 0 || b/a > 5 {` would have to be written as `if a == 0 || { b/a > 5}` in that case.  Logically `||` just takes 2 `Bool`: `func ||(lhs: Bool, rhs: Bool) -> Bool`.  By using `@autoclosure`, Swift keeps that functionality without requiring the user to provide a closure or function for the `rhs`.

Comment: @AhmadF, to be clear, it is the *closure* that provides the ability to provide the delay.  The *autoclosure* makes the syntax nice for the caller so that they don't even have to know about the *closure*.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation is all thoroughly described (with examples), but if you have any other questions, please ask me

> ### [Escaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546)
>
> A closure is said to escape a function when the closure is passed as
>   an argument to the function, but is called after the function returns.
>   When you declare a function that takes a closure as one of its
>   parameters, you can write @escaping before the parameter’s type to
>   indicate that the closure is allowed to escape.

---

> ### [Autoclosures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID543)
>
> An autoclosure is a closure that is automatically created to wrap an
>   expression that’s being passed as an argument to a function. It
>   doesn’t take any arguments, and when it’s called, it returns the value
>   of the expression that’s wrapped inside of it. This syntactic
>   convenience lets you omit braces around a function’s parameter by
>   writing a normal expression instead of an explicit closure.

Comment: I am curios if except reducing verbosity of application do we have other use of autoclosure?