# How Swift autoclosure Delaying works?

Tags: swift, closures

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) - Autoclosure Section:

> An autoclosure **lets you delay evaluation**, because the code inside
>   isn’t run until you call the closure. Delaying evaluation is useful
>   for code that has side effects or is computationally expensive,
>   because it lets you control when that code is evaluated.

I am unable to understand exactly what's the logic behind the delaying.

When I tried to compare between the standard closure and the autoclosure:

```
func getMyString() -> String {
    print("Reaching My String")
    return "My String"
}

func testStandardClousre(closure: () -> String, isValid: Bool) {
    print("Reaching Test")

    if isValid {
        _ = closure()
    }
}

// calling:
testStandardClousre(closure: { () -> String in
    return getMyString()
}, isValid: false)
```

Naturally, because `closure` wouldn't be executed, the output would be:

> Reaching Test

without printing "Reaching My String", i.e without reaching `getMyString()`.

If that's the exact case when the closure marked as `@autoclosure` (giving the same output):

```
func testAutoClosure(closure: @autoclosure () -> String, isValid: Bool) {
    print("Reaching Test")

    if isValid {
        _ = closure()
    }
}

// calling
testAutoClosure(closure: getMyString(), isValid: false)
```

So what's the meaning of delaying? i.e How delaying works?

Comment: Here's an example from today of why delaying is useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659765/1630618

Comment: This is a great blog post that shows how autoclosure came about: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippets cannot be a good example of *delaying*. If you want to find what *delaying* means, you need to compare `@autoclosure` to non-closure.

An example of non-closure:

```
enum LogLevel: Int {
    case debug, warning, error
}

extension LogLevel: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: LogLevel, rhs: LogLevel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
    }
}

var currentLogLevel: LogLevel = .error
func outputLogNonClosure(_ level: LogLevel, message: String) {
    if level >= currentLogLevel {
        print(message)
    }
}

outputLogNonClosure(.debug, message: "Debug message")
//output nothing, calling cost can be acceptable.
```

Sometimes, you may need to pass a result of complex calculation to generate the error message.

```
func getMyStringSuperHeavy() -> String {
    var result = ""
    do {
        print("Assume doing very complex calculation to get Debug message...")
        result = "Debug message"
    }
    return result
}

outputLogNonClosure(.debug, message: getMyStringSuperHeavy())
//->Assume doing very complex calculation to get Debug message......
//The result of `getMyStringSuperHeavy()` is not used, but `getMyStringSuperHeavy()` is called.
```

In the latter code above, you may want `getMyStringSuperHeavy()` not to be evaluated when the output is not needed.

---

An example of autoclosure:

```
func outputLogAutoClosure(_ level: LogLevel, message: @autoclosure ()->String) {
    if level >= currentLogLevel {
        print(message())
    }
}

outputLogAutoClosure(.debug, message: "Debug message")
//output nothing, calling cost can be acceptable.

outputLogAutoClosure(.debug, message: getMyStringSuperHeavy())
//output nothing, calling cost can be acceptable as well.
```

In the last code, the evaluation of `getMyStringSuperHeavy()` is *delay* ed till the value is actually used.

---

Generally the calculation cost of an argument declared as `arg: AType` cannot be omitted, but the value may not be needed in some cases, you can change it to `arg: @autoclosure ()->AType`, and use `arg()` when its value really is needed.

(`@autoclosure` can be used in some other cases, but you **compare `arg: AType` to `arg: @autoclosure ()->AType`** in every case.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Honestly, I am kinda surprised that in the second code snippet `getMyStringSuperHeavy()` has been evaluated! could you explain why is that? I mean what I assume is it should not be evaluated... I think that's the part that I miss.

Comment: Another question please: if we tried the same function with a non-autoclosure parameter: `func outputLogClosure(_ level: LogLevel, message: ()->String) {
    if level >= currentLogLevel {
        print(message())
    }
}` and let's say we call it like: `outputLogClosure(.debug) { () -> String in
    return "my message"
}` would it leads to the same behavior of the autoclosure parameter? I would really appreciate your time and consideration :)

Comment: @AhmadF, first point. Assuming you mean `outputLogNonClosure(.debug, message: getMyStringSuperHeavy())`. In the example, `outputLogNonClosure` is usual function, and when Swift call usual functions, Swift evaluates all actual parameters, and places the results into registers or on stack, and then invokes actual function processing. This behavior is common with many major languages, C# or Java or Objective-C.

Comment: @AhmadF, Second. The behaviors are exactly the same. The only difference is that on the calling side, you need to explicitly use closure expression. In my example above, in most use cases, we use string literals for `message`. In such cases, `outputLogAutoClosure(.debug, message: "Debug message")` would be preferred than `outputLogClosure(.debug) { () -> String in return "my message" }`. So, `@autoclosure` is sort of syntax sugar, to make typical cases simple and readable.

Comment: I got the first point. For the second point, does it mean that the only difference is the syntactic sugar of the autoclosure? which means that the standard closure should also delay...

Comment: @AhmadF, yes. In other languages which does not have autoclosure nor native _lazy_ feature, you use the standard closures to realize delayed feature. And even in Swift, you should consider using standard closures to clarify that it may be evaluated later or never. With too much `@autoclosure`s, your code would be less readable.